# Please help.How can I get the stored procedure I have created at SQL Server Management Studio using ASP.NET with VB.NET Code behind the files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I get the output data of sql procedure from SQL Server to my asp.net[vb.net] page dropdown list?`<asp:DropDownList ID="DdLocation"></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: `<asp:DropDownList ID="DdLocation"></asp:DropDownList>` is no MVC. Which one are you using? MVC or regular Asp.Net?

Comment: sorry my fault.I change it to asp.net...So Can you help me?I am so new to this.I'm a regular PHP and JS programmer.

Comment: @bertrand I am using asp.net project with vb.net codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the data from SQL to either a dataset or a datatable: http://www.google.com/search?q=vb.net+get+data+from+sql+server+to+dataset

Then on the DdLocation_Load, or Page_Load event, bind the data:

```
DdLocation.DataSource = location_data
DdLocation.DataTextField = "LocationDesc"
DdLocation.DataValueField = "LocationID"
DdLocation.DataBind()
```

Once you call DataBind, the data will be attached to the drop down list.